# Need help; I haven't finished signing up

Tags: discussion, questions

I lost my [original post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/77988/word-for-someone-who-says-yes-then-no-then-yes) before I finished signing up. What should I do? I can't post this question in Meta forum either due to my small reputation score.

Comment: Hello, @student! I'm not sure what you meant by "lost my original post". I just followed the link and I can see that your question is still there on the main site.

Comment: @DamkerngT.  I don't understand why I can't sign up. It is said **English Language Learner Stack exchange requires external java script from another domain, which is blocked and failed to load.**

Comment: Something on your end is blocking CDN, @student - proxy, firewall, company policy etc. Try browsing from a different ISP, even your mobile, and see.

Comment: You can find a comprehensive list of what needs to be working [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208/158100). Do you happen to use a mobile provider? If you are not loading the site with https you might give that a try.