# Need help from moderator(s): Could I have my post back?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I failed to log in the other day but yesterday I successfully signed up an account. 
Could I get my post back? [Here is my question on meta that I couldn't reply the other day.](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2841/need-help-i-havent-finished-signing-up)
It is my [original post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/77988/word-for-someone-who-says-yes-then-no-then-yes).

**January 11, 2016

Dear moderators, I have sent my request to merge my accounts. Just now, I received a reply from The Stack Overflow Team (?) asking my email address associated with my [unregistered account](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/28465/student). I am quoting your reason "because that's the only way I have to verify your ownership of it, which is something I need to do before performing this merge".

**My response:** Well, of course I didn't use any email address when addressing that post. Why is it complicated just to get my post back?

**January 12, 2016

I am expecting that moderator Maulik should have been wiser. By addressing "What I understand as your concern is you don't want two accounts. **You want to retain the one with more reputation as it has that 'nice question'**" you did misjudge me. 
In fact, "I want it because by keeping it I can notice the progress of my learning process. It is also easier to track the questions I have posted".

Thank you.

Comment: Please do not duplicate deleted questions. They are **deleted** for a reason.

Comment: I couldn't make any reply to that original post. a question is still a question until it is answered. So, "Could I have my post back?"

Comment: You are now here...and your post is also here...what's the problem now? (Moderator)

Comment: Are these both your profile? http://ell.stackexchange.com/users/28573/student?tab=profile **AND** https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/28465/student?tab=profile? If so, *merging* is the solution.

Comment: Yes, both are mine.

Comment: Why is it so important to get it "back"? It's still on the site, and now that you've registered properly, you can get the same amount of points rather quick.

Comment: Well, this is a standard merge issue mods should handle. Let's move on.

Comment: @CopperKettle Having two accounts lying around is never fun.

Answer (score 1):

What I understand as your concern is you don't want two accounts. You want to retain the one with more reputation as it has that 'nice question'.

Well, the best solution to this is 'merge' your accounts. So, you'll have only one account that you want.

Information on merging is here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: Moderator @Maulik: Did I say that I wish to get it back as it has more reputation? I want it because by keeping it I can notice the progress of my learning process. It is also easier to track the questions I have posted.